# How to call "QList<QVariant> QVariant::toList () const"

Tags: qt, templates, qvariant

This is a pretty simple and probably dumb question, but I have forgotten how to use *QList QVariant::toList () const*

```
QVariant s = this->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript (QString ("Open(%1,%2)").arg (point.x()).arg (point.y()));

List<QVariant> x;
x = s.toList ();
```

Of course this is wrong, what is the correct way out? :redface:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do is almost correct:

```
QList<QVariant> x = s.toList();
```

(Note the use of `QList` instead of `List`.)

Comment: That was a "typo" from my side. The actual code contains QList.

Comment: No it is not, it is producing errors which I'll soon post in OP.

Comment: :banghead: That code is correct indeed, the long errors which I was getting were due to the way I was using it:`
  
  if (x.isEmpty() == false)
  {
   for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++)
    std :: cout << "\n-----------" << x[i];
  }`

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is right. May be you can check if the variant contains a list before converting it. E.g:

```
QVariant variant = list;
if(variant.canConvert(QVariant::List))
{
    QList<QVariant> list_1 = variant.toList();
}
```